Confgure Logbook correlationId with Spring Boot 3 Webflux tracing
I would like to configure the correlationId for zalando/logbook to insert the traceId value from Spring tracing. The issue occurs when obtaining the correlationId on the request. For the response, it works fine. It seems that LogbookServerHandler is initiated too early and the traceId is not yet created, because tracer.currentSpan() returns null.
I also tried adding webFilters, but they are executed after the LogbookServerHandler. Here is a piece of code:
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@AutoConfigureBefore(LogbookWebFluxAutoConfiguration.class)
public class LogbookConfig {

    @Bean
    NettyServerCustomizer nettyServerCustomizer(Logbook logbook) {
        return (httpServer) -> (HttpServer) httpServer
                .doOnConnection((connection) -> {
                    connection.addHandlerLast(new LogbookServerHandler(logbook));
                });
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CorrelationId correlationId(Tracer tracer) {
        return request -> getTraceId(tracer);
    }

    private String getTraceId(Tracer tracer) {
        if (tracer.currentSpan() == null) {
            log.error("current span is null!");
            return null;
        }
        return tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId();
    }


Any thoughts?
